# Removing specific dictionary values inside a loop

Tags: python, dictionary, context-free-grammar

I'm trying to make a context-free grammar simplification software.
I'm stuck when it comes to delete some specific items from the dictionary's values or even the key value pair.

The problem is that it doesn't follow a pattern.

- If the element belongs to V1, I need to keep it in dictionary.
  (V1 is the list of all values who derivates a terminal, those guys are the only ones I need to keep on my dictionary, but it's not that simple)
- If the element doesn't belongs to V1 and dictionary's values is a string, I need to remove the element.
- If the element doesn't belongs to V1 and dictionary's values is a list, I need to check if it's the single element of that list, if so, delete Value.

The failed loop is down here.
I printed the parts that I can't figure out the logic in modifying the dictionary.

```
counter = 0
for k,v in derivations.items():
    derivationsCount = len(v)

    while counter < derivationsCount:
        if lista_ou_string(v[counter]): # returns True for lists, False for else
            sizeOfList = len(v[counter])
            counter2 = 0

            while counter2 <= (sizeOfList - 1):
                if v[counter][counter2] not in V1:
                    if derivationsCount == 1:
                        print("# NEED TO DELETE BOTH KEY AND VALUE FROM derivatios.items()")
                    else:
                        print("# NEED TO DELETE ONLY THE VALUE FROM derivations.items()")
                counter2 += 1

        else: # strings \/
            if v[counter] not in V1:
                if derivationsCount == 1:
                    print("# NEED TO DELETE BOTH KEY AND VALUE FROM derivatios.items()")
                else:
                    print("# NEED TO DELETE ONLY THE VALUE FROM derivations.items()")
            else:
                print("# DO NOT DELETE ANYTHING! ALL LISTS ELEMENTS BELONGS TO 'V1'")
        counter += 1
```

Comment: can you share structure of `derivations` ?

Comment: `for k,v in derivations.items():` is badly indented, wrong copy/paste?

Comment: There's no such thing as "deleting only the value" from a dictionary, the key has to map to something. Do you mean to make the value `None`?

Comment: derivations example after reading .txt: {'S': [['X', 'Y', 'Z']], 'A': ['a'], 'B': ['b'], 'X': [['A', 'X', 'A'], ['B', 'X', 'B'], 'Z', 'V'], 'Y': [['A', 'Y', 'B'], ['B', 'Y', 'A'], 'Z', 'V'], 'Z': [['Z', 'u'], ['Z', 'v'], 'V']}

Comment: What is `derivationsCount`?

Comment: This sentence makes no sense: _"If the element doesn't belongs to V1 and dictionary's values is a list, I need to check if it's the single element of that list, if so, delete Value."_ What is an _"element"_ here? Do you actually mean that "element" is a value in the list that is a value in your `derivations` dictionary?

Comment: Fixed. Portuguese is my main language. I forgot to translate 'quantidadeProducoes' into 'derivationsCount'. Sorry

Comment: Exactly, the element can be inside a list, or a single string. like the derivations example above. [['X', 'Y','Z']] is a list that has 3 elements.

Comment: Have you checked out my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One does not want to modify a dictionary (or list) while looping over it. Therefore I create a copy of the `derivations` - `new_derivations` and modify this `new_derivations`:

```
import copy
new_derivations = copy.deepcopy(derivations)
for k, v in derivations.items():
    for vi in v:
        if (lista_ou_string(vi) and not set(vi).issubset(V1)) or vi not in V1:
            if len(v) == 1:
                # NEED TO DELETE BOTH KEY AND VALUE FROM derivatios.items()
                del new_derivations[k]
                break
            else:
                # NEED TO DELETE ONLY THE VALUE FROM derivations.items()
                idx = new_derivations[k].index(vi)
                del new_derivations[k][idx]
```

---

I would actually implement the above code differently: instead of thinking in terms of removing items from `derivations`, think instead of when an element should be added to the list. Then the code becomes much simpler:

```
new_derivations = {}
for k, v in derivations.items():
    nv = [vi for vi in v if ((isinstance(vi, list) and set(vi).issubset(V1))
                             or vi in V1)]
    if nv:
        new_derivations[k] = nv
```

Comment: Oh, that’s nice. Thank you! Gonna give it a shot when I get home

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete a key,value pair from a dictionary, use `del`:

```
>>> my_dictionary = {'foo':'bar', 'boo':'baz'}
>>> del my_dictionary['foo']
>>> my_dictionary
{'boo': 'baz'}
```

if you want to delete the value, but keep the key, you can try assigning key `None`:

```
>>> my_dictionary = {'foo':'bar', 'boo':'baz'}
>>> my_dictionary['foo'] = None
>>> my_dictionary
{'foo': None, 'boo': 'baz'}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this inside the while:

del derivations[k]

But it's returning Key Error: ' ?? ' 
?? is the key I'm trying to remove alongside all it's values.

Any fix for this?